# Auto-Scroll Fast in JS

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I have a `HTML` which is very long. I would like to auto-scroll the content on load. My requirements are:

1. Go to top when page opened.
2. Scroll to the utmost bottom.

Here's what I tried:

```
function pageScroll() {
  window.scrollBy(0,7000);
  scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',1000);
}
```

This works well but I want it to be faster and also I would like a replacement of `7000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the values which should work best in my opinion

```js
function pageScroll() {
    window.scrollBy(0, 3060) //don't set a timeout function
}
pageScroll()
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, it worked! I was trying this since 30 mins :)